# Create a comma separated string with numbers 1 to x, where x is read from the record

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table `document` with a field `steps`. This is an integer field and can contain a number between 1 and 1000.

Now a new field is added (`followedsteps`) which must contain the numbers from 1 to [the number from field steps], comma separated.

So when the field `steps` contains the number 5, I want this string `1,2,3,4,5` to be set in the new column `followedsteps`.

The field `steps` is not null-able, lowest value is 1.

Is there an (easy) way to do this?

It's a one time migration.

Comment: Have a look on stackoverflow.com for "group_concat" under t-sql and sql-server tags. There's a few solutions that exist that'll do this easily for you.

Comment: @JonathonOgden I'm familiar with the various ways you can implement `group_concat`-type behaviour in MSSQL, but how would you solve the additional issue of needing to have all of the positive integer values lower than the value in `steps`? I can't see any examples within the `group_concat` questions you mention - would you need to use a numbers table, or make some wacky call to `ROW_NUMBER()` to get a list of all numbers from 1 to 1000?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are going to perform this only one time, it will be better to generate first the sequences:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DataSource') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN;
    DROP TABLE #DataSource;
END;

CREATE TABLE #DataSource
(
    [ID] INT
   ,[Sequence] VARCHAR(MAX)
);

DECLARE @MaximumID INT = 1000; -- in your case: SELECT MAX(steps) FROM document 

WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS num
    UNION ALL
    SELECT num+1 
    FROM DataSource 
    WHERE num+1<=@MaximumID
)
INSERT INTO #DataSource
SELECT A.[num]
      ,DS.[Sequence]
FROM DataSource A
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT STUFF
    (
        (
            SELECT ',' + CAST(B.[num] AS VARCHAR(12))
            FROM DataSource B
            WHERE A.[num] >= B.[num]
            ORDER BY B.[num]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1
        ,1
        ,''
    )
) DS ([Sequence])
option (maxrecursion 32767)
```

The code above creates a temporary table with data you need to perform the update:

[image]

Then in transaction, perform the update by `[ID]`:

```
 BEGIN TRAN

    UPDATE document 
    SET followedsteps = [Sequence]
    FROM document A
    INNER JOIN ##DataSource B
        ON A.[steps] = b.[id]

COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: Missed the 1 time migration line +1